# Can I transform a layout view to a pdf file in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, pdf

I need to generate a pdf file where its content is full of tables and images to fill, the idea would be to create a layout view and with that generate the pdf file

Comment: Hi, if my anwer helped you please accept it ;)

Comment: Hi, yes, it helped me a little, but I still can't find a solution

Comment: What do you mean? What problem exactly do you have now?

Comment: I need to create PDF files, with tables and images, in the easiest way. So I was wondering if a view could be converted as a pdf file from the native android library or some other that simplifies a lot of work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
In order to do that you can use `android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument`.
Inflate your layout and then let it draw on canvas of your document, e.g.:

`rootView.draw(pdfDoc.getCanvas())`